# Adding an Image overlay to video

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

Looking to add an image overlay to this video I have playing in fullscreen. I was wondering what the best route would be to achieve this? This will be a PNG image with transparency. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class videoViewController: UIViewController, UIApplicationDelegate{


var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
    self.playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
    self.videoPlayer!.play()

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("continueVideo:"), name: "continueVideo", object: nil)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidReachEnd:"), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
}


func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.videoPlayer.play()
}

func continueVideo(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.videoPlayer.play()
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.pause()
}


func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.pause()
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



}
```

Comment: have you tried adding the uiimageview on top of the self.view after adding the layer?

Comment: I have tried UIImageView but I am not really sure how to do that properly or where to even add it. When I try I get a blank screen with sound playing.

Comment: what are the properties of the uiimageview? is it opaque?

Comment: If it's an overlay you can just add it as subview of self.view. If it's a backgroundview you can try self.playerLayer.contents = image.CGImage

Comment: @HMHero Adding it as a subView worked! Thank you so much.